# Can anyone identify this early 20th century european costume/uniform?

Tags: world-war-one, identification, uniform

[image]

Can anyone identify this costume/uniform for me? I am wondering if anyone recognises it or could connect it to any particular country or conflict. We found it in an album belonging to a great aunt who was born in 1901 in Corsica and then lived in the south of France.  I would date it to around WW1 but it does not look like a regular military uniform.  Any ideas?